# Do the functions in L hopitals rule need to be continuous on a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Cauchy's mean value theorem requires that the two functions $f$ and $g$
are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. However, L'Hopital's rule (as stated in the text I am reading) only requires the following conditions: \begin{gather}
\text{$f$ and $g$ are differentiable on an open interval $I$
with one of the end points being $c$} \\
g(x) \neq 0 \quad \forall x \in I \\
g'(x) \neq 0 \quad \forall x \in I \\
f(c)=g(c)= 0 \\
\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}= L.
\end{gather}
Cauchy's mean value theorem is used on subintervals of the form $(c,x), x \in I$ in the proof, which seems
inappropriate because there's nothing to say $f$ and $g$
are continuous on $[c,x]$. How can CMVT be used if this condition isn't satisfied?

Comment: I'm guessing you can get away with continuity on $(c,x]$, but I don't see how $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$.

Comment: When I look at the wikipedia page, it is not stated this way. What is the text you are reading?

Comment: What l'Hopitals rule aims at is the situation where $f, g$ both tend to $0$ (or both diverge to $\pm \infty$ when $x\rightarrow c$. The statement $f(c)= g(c) =0$ is _not_ relevant, and the value of $f/g$ in this case is undefined, anyway.

Comment: You can assume that (i) $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$ with $f(c)=g(c)=0$ or (ii) that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=0$.  Those are equivalent for the proof.  What you *cannot* get away with is to drop continuity and expect $f(c)=g(c)=0$ to have any use whatsoever.

Comment: Ah ok. It isn't stated properly in the text then.